# A no specific query using Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, nosql

I've downloaded a database yesterday consistent of tweets during the games in the confederation cup. And I saved it in the Mongo DB. My data model in the database is like the following json:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc9036194069119ff88c10"),
  "text" : "Adianta AGORA ir para ruas e   protesta, como em Brasilia e outras capitais contra a copa das confederações e do... http://t.co/41e4GGoe4o",
  "created_at" : "2013-06-15 16:03:02",
  "id" : NumberLong("345934481724669954"),
  "user" : { "image" : "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3425436378/57edc83f19d834283351a3729595d480_normal.jpeg",
             "screen_name" : "Fernando_Fontes",
             "id" : 54433693,
             "name" : "Fernando Fontes" 
           } 
}
```

Now, I wish to retrieve tweets using a term from the field 'text', for example: 'Brasilia'. But, I couldn't make a query searching for part of the text. I'm still starting with NoSQL and Big Data things. Is there any way to find the documents which has a word inside the field 'text'?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Thiago

Comment: why don't use make regex query, db.coll.find({text : /Brasilia/ })

Comment: how did you determine these were tweets related to the games?  Or do you mean you got all of the tweets and you are searching for ones that are related to the games?  Was there a hashtag that would identify those?  Normally there is an "entities" document in the tweet with several arrays, one of them is "hashtags" and the "text" field would have the hashtag text.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek Kumar. It works perfectly. This will reduce processing of the retrieving of tweets. Asya Kamsky, I'm aiming to determine if the tweets are related to the games and protests in Brazil yesterday. Actually my search terms was very selective to find what I want, but, certainlly I will remove some others tweets that has nothing to do to the games. Unfortunatally, this is not perfect and some noises will pass in this filter.